# RTSP link not found in source

Tags: youtube, media-player, rtsp

I am fixing some old `RTSP` YouTube player made for `Symbian` devices which is used in Blackberry or Nokia 3GP mobile phones.

Couple of weeks ago it was working and I was able to stream and watch the videos, since yesterday I get back to the code and try to continue my tasks but when I put the breakpoint on the GET RTSP link, it can not found anymore from response source.

Despite I wrote to YouTube if they stopped supporting this I get no answer and I am also paid YouTube developer and also I have paid Gmail and I feel like this covid situation makes everyone waiting.

If there is someone who have experience with this RTSP 3GP players and know some info please comment if this is deprecated or I should stop focusing on fixing this code player and look for additional task or it is working and I need some other info or source to make it work again..

**My response when it was working get this rtsp link:**

```
rtsp://r2---sn-q4flrn7r.googlevideo.com:554/Cj0LENy73wIaNAlQN5SaCYfUwBMYESARFC2LT9ZeMOCoAUIASARgyffQ77Xxk-teigELemo1OFdoSXNsSlkM/78FAEBAEB3541F6B4C128E9C594EFCF7BF50A2F9.38FCBF08BF6550B599C4AB4BE2FD62C2837C7802/yt8/1/video.3gp
```

**USERAGENT:** *(I tried different agents but no success*)

```
NokiaC5-00/061.005 (SymbianOS/9.3; U; Series60/3.2 Mozilla/5.0; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1) AppleWebKit/525 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Safari/525 3gpp-gba
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google dropped RSTP support when API v2.0 was discontinued.